# Merge JS Replace function into one line of code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to concatenate three replace Regex code into one.
In the following example I have remove `DIV, I, IMG` tags from title. It's a expected behavior. The only problem with concatenation.

Anyone help me achieve this.

```js
text = $('.text').attr('title')
//console.log(text)
bind = text.replace(/<(span|i)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>/g, '').replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, '').replace(/<\/?div[^>]*>/g, '')
console.log(bind)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="Lorem Ipsum<div><img src='test.png'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>" class="text">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</div>
```

Comment: [Regex can't safely parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Why not use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to do this more safely?

Comment: @spender I'm not familiar with DOMParser. I prefer Regex here.

Comment: To help with gaining familiarity, I posted a DOMParser-based solution anyway. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML with RegExp is probably a bad idea and will result in a brittle solution.

Why not just parse with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead and then ask the resulting `document` for its `innerText`?

```js
const attribString = "Lorem Ipsum<div><img src='test.png'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>";
const dp = new DOMParser();
const doc = dp.parseFromString(attribString, "text/html");
const text = doc.documentElement.innerText;
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Great! Working fine

Answer (score 1):

I think `DOMParser` is a bit overkill. How about a solution using a temporary virtual div element? Snippet using vanilla js:

```js
const elem = Object.assign(
  document.createElement(`div`), {
    innerHTML: document.querySelector(`div.text`).title
  }
);
console.log(elem.textContent);
```

```html
<div 
  title="Lorem Ipsum<div><img src='test.png'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></div>" 
  class="text">
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
</div>
```